# ViewResolver not working properly in Spring 4

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

My ViewResolver is not working as expected. I have multiple controllers for handling different requests. Below are Code snippets:

AppConfig class

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"in.andonsystem"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

}
```

DispatcherConfig class:

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"in.andonsystem.controllers"})
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return viewResolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource(){
      ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      messageSource.setBasename("messages");     
      return messageSource;
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
   }
}
```

AppInitializer Class

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
      servletContext.addListener(ContextListener.class);

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
   }
}
```

MiscController Class

```
package in.andonsystem.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MiscController {

   @RequestMapping("/")
   public String index(){
      return "index";
   }
}
```

SectionController Class

```
package in.andonsystem.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/section")
public class SectionController {

   @RequestMapping(name = "/show",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String showSection(){
      System.out.println("Section");
      return "section";
   }

}
```

The Problem which I am facing is When I access url `{context path}/section/show` It is redirected to showSection() method of SectionController, "Section" is printed on stdout but then it forwards to `{root context}/section/WEB-INF/views/section.jsp`  instead of `{root context}/WEB-INF/views/section.jsp`

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

otherwise forward is relative to request URL.